# Arrange values within a specific group

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I'm trying to arrange values in decreasing order within a exact group in a nested dataframe. My input data looks like this. I've got two grouping variables (`group1` and `group2`) and three values (i.e. `id`, `value2`, `value3`).

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1234)    

df <- tibble(group1 = c(rep(LETTERS[1:3], 4)),
             group2 = c(rep(0, 6), rep(2, 6)),
             value2 = rnorm(12, 20, sd = 10),
             value3 = rnorm(12, 20, sd = 50)) %>%  
  group_by(group1) %>% 
  mutate(id = c(1:4)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

I decided to group them by `group1` and `group2` and then `nest()`:

```
df_nested <- df %>% 
  group_by(group1, group2) %>% 
  nest()

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   group1, group2 [6]
  group1 group2 data            
  <chr>   <dbl> <list>          
1 A           0 <tibble [2 x 3]>
2 B           0 <tibble [2 x 3]>
3 C           0 <tibble [2 x 3]>
4 A           2 <tibble [2 x 3]>
5 B           2 <tibble [2 x 3]>
6 C           2 <tibble [2 x 3]>
```

Perfect. Now I need to sort only those `data` which `group2` is equal to `2` by `id`. However I'm receiving a following error:

```
df_nested %>% 
  mutate(data = map2_df(.x = data, .y = group2,
                     ~ifelse(.y == 2, arrange(-.x$id),
                             .x)))
```

> Error: Argument 1 must have names

Comment: Can you use `set.seed` to generate random data and show expected output? Do you want to arrange by all value columns? Also I don't think `arrange(-.x)` does what you are expecting it to do. Check `arrange(-mtcars)`, it just multiplies the data by `-1`.

Comment: You need to define by which variables and in which order you want to arrange your nested dataframes. You can't simply `arrange`.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I've added `set.seed` and `id` column. I need to arrange by `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df_nested$data <- map2(df_nested$data, df_nested$group2,~if(.y == 2) 
                       arrange(.x, -.x$id) else .x)
```

So data where `group2` is not equal to 2 is not sorted

```
df_nested$data[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  value2 value3    id
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
#1  13.1  -89.0      1
#2   9.76  -3.29     2
```

and where `group2` is 2 is sorted.

```
df_nested$data[[4]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#value2 value3    id
# <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
#1   15.0  -28.4   4
#2   31.0  -22.8   3
```

If you want to combine them do :

```
map2_df(df_nested$data, df_nested$group2,~if(.y == 2) arrange(.x, -.x$id) else .x)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating an additional variable `id_` which will be equal to the original `id` variable when `group2 == 2` and `NA` otherwise. This way if we use it in sorting it'll make no effect when `group2 != 2`.

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(id_ = if_else(group2 == 2, id, NA_integer_)) %>% 
  arrange(group1, group2, -id_)
#> # A tibble: 12 x 6
#>    group1 group2 value2 value3    id   id_
#>    <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <int>
#>  1 A           0   17.6  50.2      1    NA
#>  2 A           0   33.8 -14.4      2    NA
#>  3 A           2   23.1  22.6      4     4
#>  4 A           2   13.7  50.2      3     3
#>  5 B           0   15.4  49.9      1    NA
#>  6 B           0   16.2  63.7      2    NA
#>  7 B           2   41.7  -2.90     4     4
#>  8 B           2   16.6  46.7      3     3
#>  9 C           0   19.9 -64.3      1    NA
#> 10 C           0   19.9  59.7      2    NA
#> 11 C           2   34.1  48.5      4     4
#> 12 C           2   32.3  23.1      3     3
```

Then if needed we can group and nest the result.