# Sort/arrange within group for only chosen groups

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

I would like to sort/arrange data by group. That's easy enough. However, I only want to sort values within specific groups, not all groups.

I found one possible instance of a similar question at the link. But I found it to be confusing due to the framing of the question by the OP.
[Arrange values within a specific group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60224883/arrange-values-within-a-specific-group)

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(var = c("apple", "banana", "eggplant", "carrot", "dill", "fava", "garlic"), 
                 grp = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C"), 
                 val = c(4, 2, 1, 3, 7, 6, 2))
df
#        var grp val
# 1    apple   A   4
# 2   banana   A   2
# 3   carrot   B   3
# 4     dill   B   7
# 5 eggplant   B   1
# 6     fava   C   6
# 7   garlic   C   2
```

Desired output:

```
#        var grp val
# 1    apple   A   4
# 2   banana   A   2
# 3 eggplant   B   1
# 4   carrot   B   3
# 5     dill   B   7
# 6   garlic   C   2
# 7     fava   C   6
```

Partial solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  arrange(val, .by_group = T)
```

This of course sorts for all groups. How do I get it to sort for only the groups I would like sorted, which are "B" and "C"? I would like a `tidyverse` solution but feel free to post a `base` solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change the sign to the elements in 'val' that correspond to "A" group so that it is ordered in the opposite direction compared to the 'val' elements in other group

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
      arrange(grp, val * c(1, -1)[(grp == 'A') + 1])
```

-output

```
        var grp val
1    apple   A   4
2   banana   A   2
3 eggplant   B   1
4   carrot   B   3
5     dill   B   7
6   garlic   C   2
7     fava   C   6
```

Or if the values for 'A' should be kept as such, then mltiply by 0 so that each value is same for 'A'

```
df %>%
      arrange(grp, val * c(1, 0)[(grp == 'A') + 1])
           var grp val
1    apple   A   4
2   banana   A   2
3 eggplant   B   1
4   carrot   B   3
5     dill   B   7
6   garlic   C   2
7     fava   C   6
```

NOTE: This is done without any `group_by` attribute

---

If we want to use the OP's way, i.e. using `group_by`

```
df %>% 
   group_by(grp)  %>%
    arrange(case_when(grp == 'A' ~ -1 * val, TRUE ~ val), 
         .by_group = TRUE) %>%
    ungroup
```

-ouptutu

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  var      grp     val
  <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
1 apple    A         4
2 banana   A         2
3 eggplant B         1
4 carrot   B         3
5 dill     B         7
6 garlic   C         2
7 fava     C         6
```

---

If the values in 'val' for grp 'A' are showed in descending order because of coincidence, then create a sequence column before doing the grouping and then use that for modifying

```
df %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    group_by(grp)  %>%
    arrange(case_when(grp == 'A' ~ as.numeric(rn), TRUE ~ val), 
         .by_group = TRUE) %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    dplyr::select(-rn)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  var      grp     val
  <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
1 apple    A         4
2 banana   A         2
3 eggplant B         1
4 carrot   B         3
5 dill     B         7
6 garlic   C         2
7 fava     C         6
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df[with(df, order(grp, c(1, 0)[(grp == 'A') + 1] * val)),]
       var grp val
1    apple   A   4
2   banana   A   2
3 eggplant   B   1
4   carrot   B   3
5     dill   B   7
7   garlic   C   2
6     fava   C   6
```

Comment: You're the man, akrun! This works, although it is a bit difficult to decipher what's going on, not that that's your fault. I blame Hadley. It was the third solution in particular that worked. The others were inconsistently moving around rows in the other groups in my actual data. Using the sequence column solved it perfectly, though I swapped it out for `rownames(.)`. That should be okay in general, right?

Comment: @hmhensen the row_number would be better though as it is integer value and thus won't have any other issue in character problem which may order differently

Comment: @hmhensen the first two solutions are a bit hacky way to solve this i.e. if you multioply the numeric column by 0 all elements will be 0 and thus the order will be the same as in the original order, whereas multiplying by 1, returns the original value and thus order based on value

Comment: Thanks. Also, for anyone else reading this, if you want to sort descending for the chosen groups, use `TRUE ~ desc(val)` in the `case_when`.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the groups you want to arrange, sort them and bind to the remaining data.

```
library(dplyr)

order_groups <- c('B', 'C')

df %>%
  filter(grp %in% order_groups) %>%
  arrange(grp, val) %>%
  bind_rows(df %>%
             filter(!grp %in% order_groups)) %>%
  arrange(grp)

#.      var grp val
#1    apple   A   4
#2   banana   A   2
#3 eggplant   B   1
#4   carrot   B   3
#5     dill   B   7
#6   garlic   C   2
#7     fava   C   6
```